# Javascript só funciona após dois cliques

Tags: javascript

Estou usando um menu lateral num site e queria que ele retraísse com um clique no botão... acontece que isso só está acontecendo após dois cliques!!

```
function resp() {

   var clique = document.getElementById("btn-menu");

   var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");



   clique.onclick = function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');

  };

}
```

Estou usando um link para chamar a função script: `<a href="#" onClick="resp()" id="btn-menu">`

> menu-lateral é o id da div do menu lateral
>
> toggleMenu é  a classe que é adicionada a div do menu lateral

Esse código eu peguei como base de outra pessoa, porém ela não usava como function() e não tinha um onClick na tag ... porém assim o meu não funciona... alguém sabe o que pode ser?? é chato ter que clicar duas vezes pro menu retrair (isso só acontece no primeiro toque depois de atualizado a página)

Comment: Por favor, marque uma das respostas com ✓. Não precisa ser a minha, mas é muito importante marcar uma resposta que lhe ajudou ou então informar o que não ajudou. Obg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa da função `resp()` e nem mesmo do `onClick` no elemento. Apenas o evento `onclick = function` já captura o click e resolve o problema. Da forma que está fazendo, está chamando duas funções após o primeiro click.

#### Usando `.onclick`

```js
var clique = document.getElementById("btn-menu");
var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");
clique.onclick = function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');
};
```

```css
.toggleMenu{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"  id="btn-menu">Menu</a>
<br />
<div id="menu-lateral">
   itens do menu
</div>
```

#### Usando `onclick`

```js
function resp() {
   var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");
   menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');
}
```

```css
.toggleMenu{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resp()" id="btn-menu">Menu</a>
<br />
<div id="menu-lateral">
   itens do menu
</div>
```

**Alternativamente**, você pode chamar a função direto no `href`:

```js
function resp() {
   var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");
   menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');
}
```

```css
.toggleMenu{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:resp()" id="btn-menu">Menu</a>
<br />
<div id="menu-lateral">
   itens do menu
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que da forma que você está fazendo, você está chamando a função `resp` e depois atribuindo uma nova ação ao botão `btn-menu`

Você não precisa adicionar o evento `onclick` novamente.

`<a href="#" onClick="return resp()" id="btn-menu">`

```
function resp() {
   var menuLateral = document.getElementById("menu-lateral");
   menuLateral.classList.toggle('toggleMenu');

   return false;
}
```